# Zabbix web-scenario with Authentication

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, zabbix

I want to check service availability with zabbix. On my server I have Tomcat and java app deployed, which is contacting external server (GET request), and it is working (when the service is available). Communication between java app and external server is encrypted, I have .jks file, which I exported to .pem format.
I created folder /etc/zabbix/ssl and putted my .pem file there. I edited my zabbix_server.conf like this:

```
SSLCertLocation=/etc/zabbix/ssl/
SSLKeyLocation=/etc/zabbix/ssl/
```

My web scenario Authentication is set like this:

[image: web scenario auth.jpg]

But, no score. 
Can someone explain what should I do in order to make it work? 
I am using zabbix 3.4

I am new to zabbix, please excuse me if my question is trivial.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! "No score" is not enough information to help you. Your question needs to include What have you tried? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? What does your config look like? Do you have any log entries from the times it didn't work as expected?

Comment: Hi, I tried to send GET request to external server, same as java app does, and expected to get response from it. But instead I get Connection timeout. My config is pretty much default, I just changed parameters SSLCertLocation and SSLKeyLocation (both are in the same file). I have test server that is not using SSL and it works, so I know that Step is configured properly.

Comment: If you get a connection timeout, then it's a networking issue not an authentication issue.

Comment: So, maybe I am doing something wrong... Here's the situation: I have zabbix server, another server with Tomcat and zabbix agent. Can you explain me: is agent trying to contact external server when I set web-scenario for that host? Or external server is contacted from zabbix server?